# How to add jQuery into a VuePress file

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuepress

I have a project that I want to document with VuePress, and I have a small code that requires jQuery to run. I know you can add inline script tags and put code in them, but I can't seem to be able to add jQuery. Here is the folder structure and what I've tried:

```
docs
   .vuepress
   -- dist
   -- public
      -- css
      -- js
         -- jquery-3.3.1.min.js
         -- scripts.js
   -- config.js
   components.md
```

and in components.md I added the following at the end:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the error when adding jquery in the script tag:

```
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?vue&type=script&lang=js&' in C:/Users/../docs
 @ ./node_modules/vuepress/lib/app/.temp/routes.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuepress/lib/app/app.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuepress/lib/app/clientEntry.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/vuepress/lib/app/clientEntry.js
```

Adding the css in config.js in `module.exports.head` works, but for some reason adding javascript doesn't work (jquery gets added, but sometimes it works and most of the time it doesn't). Here's what I tried in config.js

```
head: [
["link",{ rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/bootstrap-4.1.3/bootstrap reboot.css" } ],
["link",{ rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/bootstrap-4.1.3/bootstrap-grid.css"}],
["link", { rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/bootstrap-custom.css" }],
["link", { rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/style.css" }],
["script", { src: "/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" }],
["script", { src: "/js/scripts.js" }]
]
```

EDIT: I tested a bit more and apparently, even though the scripts are imported, I can't select the element I want to select. For example $('.my-elements') returns an empty selector. On the other hand document.getElementsByClassName('my-elements') works and shows the element I want as the first array element, but if I want to select that first array element with [0] at the end it returns undefined.

I tried selecting elements in the console using the 2 functions above. The same functions work in the console but don't work in the script, this is weird.

Comment: What do you mean whith "sometimes it works and most of the time it doesn't" ? It's seems to be a script executed before jquery loading. Often resolved with a $( document ).ready(function() {});

Comment: Yeah I forgot that, but even though I added it it still doesn't work. As for what I meant, I think it worked once when I imported the scripts, but never again so far.

I tested a bit and apparently, even though the scripts are imported, I can't select the element I want to select. For example $('.my-element') returns an empty selector. document.getElementsByClassName('my-element') works and shows the element I want, but if I want to select the first array element with [0] at the end it returns undefined.

Comment: Add that in config.js in the head section. see: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#head

Answer (score 4):

In

```
.vuepress/config.js
```

add script

```
module.exports = {
    head: [
        ['script', {src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'}]
    ]
}
```

Further docs about head config

> https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#head

jQuery CDN

> https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

just to add, for vitepress if anyone is using, (the newer `1.0.0-alpha45`) has now changed for defining `.vitepress/config.js`

```
export default {
    head: [
        ['script', {src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.slim.min.js'}]
    ]
}
```